# Get file details from Share Path using SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

I am executing the below query in SQL server 2008 to get the file details from the shared path.

```
DECLARE @ExecString VARCHAR(255)
SELECT @ExecString = 'dir \\<HostName>\D$\DBObjects\DBObjects_v*.SQL /B'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @ExecString
```

It is error out and returning below error message

```
Login failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

If I copy the exact query and run it to Command prompt, provides the proper result. Below is the query executed by CMD Prompt

```
dir \\<HostName>\D$\DBObjects\DBObjects_v*.SQL /B
```

Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Microsoft KB patch changing UAC restrictions on the network. Due to which, unable to access the network path of host server from store server so the required files are not copying from Host server to Store server.

Disable UAC remote restrictions to fix for this issue
Add `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` key with value 1 in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`

Refer below link for more details
https://helgeklein.com/blog/2011/08/access-denied-trying-to-connect-to-administrative-shares-on-windows-7/